# Is this code endian-safe?

Tags: c++, file, portability, endianness

To be totally sure, I would like to know if the following C++ code is safe and especially endian safe? I want this program to be able to write from any computer in a binary file and then read the file from any other computer (that can have another endianness) (i.e to be portable).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define BUFF_SIZE 64

template <typename type> void toBin(type value, char * buffer, size_t size);
template <typename type> type toDec(char * buffer, size_t size);

int main()
{
    long long x = 238920134300912;

    char * buffer = (char*)calloc(BUFF_SIZE, sizeof(char));

    // Write x
    toBin<long long>(x, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);

    ofstream outFile("test.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

    outFile.write(buffer, BUFF_SIZE);

    outFile.close();

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Read x (from another computer...)
    ifstream inFile("test.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);

    inFile.read(buffer, BUFF_SIZE);

    cout << toDec<long long>(buffer, BUFF_SIZE) << endl;

    inFile.close();


    // Free the buffer.
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}



template <typename type> void toBin(type value, char * buffer, size_t size)
{
    if (sizeof(type) > size)
        throw new invalid_argument("Buffer too small");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(type); i++)
        buffer[i] = (value >> i * 8) & 0xff;
}


template <typename type> type toDec(char * buffer, size_t size)
{
    if (sizeof(type) > size)
        throw new invalid_argument("Buffer too small");

    type value = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(type); i++)
        value += ((type)buffer[i] & 0xff) << (8 * i);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just read/write directly the binary???

Comment: @Walter Because that’s definitely *not* endian portable.

Comment: You realize that e.g. `sizeof(long)` is different on different machines, right? You can only use this with fixed-size types like uint32_t.

Comment: Incidentally, **never** throw a pointer.

Comment: Do not use `*alloc/free` (and the C-style casts) in C++ code. No. Use RAII or stack allocated variables.

Answer (score 2):

It looks good to me except one thing. I would replace `8` by `CHAR_BIT` and `0xff` by `UCHAR_MAX`.

```
buffer[i] = (value >> (i * CHAR_BIT)) & UCHAR_MAX;
```

and

```
value += ((type)buffer[i] & UCHAR_MAX) << (CHAR_BIT * i);
```

Comment: What's the point of using CHAR_BIT and 0xff next to each other? ;)

Comment: @KonradRudolph *in C++, char is defined to be 8 bits* {citation needed}

Comment: What's the point of really caring about systems with more that 8 bits per byte? BTW, casting to `char` is better: the compiler will handle the storage.

Comment: @n.m. Hmm, I thought I remembered that the standard somewhere had the restriction that `sizeof(char)` < `sizeof(int16_t)` or `char16_t` or something like that, which would imply that it’s always 8 bits. Apparently I was wrong.

Comment: @black, are you talking about `(type)buffer[i]`?

Comment: Thanks! Can I replace `0xff` by `const unsigned char MASK = -1;`

Comment: @Sierpinski, `unsigned char` and `-1`? How will that be better than `0xff`?

Comment: @RSahu because if CHAR_BIT is not equal to 8 then `0xff` is not correct

Comment: @RSahu Yup. The compiler will figure it out.

Comment: @Sierpinski, I think the best option is `UCHAR_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [`htons()` family of functions](http://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/htonsman.html). They are library functions which convert between the host's endianness to "network byte-order" i.e. big-endianness. These functions are guaranteed to be portable and likely to be faster than your own implementation.

If you want to ensure portability, you should also test the code on several platforms, to make sure that it actually works. In a large program, you are very likely to forget to convert the endianness somewhere. The program would still work on the original platform, so you need to test it on another to detect the bug.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I test my program on other architecture (with other endianness) ? Is there some tools or VM to do that?

Comment: It depends which platform you would like to port the program to. There is no such thing as complete portability in practice, only portability for specific platforms. If you don't have a specific plaform in mind, you shouldn't worry about portable endianness anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, but it's slow.

Alternatively, simply write with the data (in a portable way) a flag indicating endianness of the data on file (your write program may even take a boolean argument indicating which endianness it should write, defaulting to the value of the current hardware). Then, the reading code can detect whether the endianness is compliant and, if needed, flip the bytes in place.

In the likely case that writer and reader have the same endianness, this adds only a tiny overhead to an ordinary I/O. AFAIK, this is the way portable binary formats are usually implemented (such as HDF5).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it's true, but performance doesn't really matter in my case, It's only for few numbers.